# Python Camelot - How to remove line beaks /n from table

Tags: python, dataframe, pdf

How do i remove/replace /n characters from Camelot table?

I'm trying to parse PDF file into table, which contains cells with multiple line breaks.
Not sure if its a BUG, but sequence is messed up because of those characters.

Answer (score 4):

Bit late to the party here but, since Camelot returns a panda dataframe you can use

`tables[0].df = tables[0].df.replace('\\n',' ', regex=True)`

Answer (score 1):

This can be resolved with the help of `strip_text` parameter

eg :

`tables = camelot.read_pdf('12s0324.pdf', flavor='stream', strip_text=' .\n')`

[reference](https://camelot-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/advanced.html#strip-characters-from-text)

Comment: it cannot be resolved like this. Problem is that instead of GPH\nW\n1900 program is reading out "W 1\nGPH\n900". It looks like script cannot handle multiple line breaks.

Answer (score 0):

```
File = "C:\Users\ABCD\Downloads\XYZ\Folder\Folder2\xyz.pdf"
tables2 = camelot.read_pdf(File,pages="all",flavor="lattice") # ,strip_text=' .\n'

def Remove_all_line_breaks(text):
    """  Remove all line breaks from a string """

    return([i.replace("\n"," ") for i in text])




temp_df = tables2[0].df
temp_df.columns = Remove_all_line_breaks(temp_df.iloc[0])
temp_df = temp_df[1:]
```